# ClickOnce, reflection and security

Tags: .net, security, clickonce, appdomain

I have developed a .net desktop application which is distribuited to my clients as a clickonce application.

This applications need to download a dll from my server and after that load it by reflection. The dll is downloaded correctly, but when i try to load it using:

```
Dim dom As AppDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(Guid.NewGuid.ToString)
Dim a As Reflection.Assembly = Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(dllPath)
```

I get this error:

```
System.Securyty.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
```

Looking for a solution, i found that i need to change the clickonce security as "This is a partil trust application". However, if i set this level of security after publish and reinstall, when i try to launch the application i get:

```
Microsoft.ClickOnce.Utility has stopped working
```

And no more info. After look for a solution for this new problem, i only found that i need to change security to "This is a full trust application".

However i will get the first error. How can i get this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. This is the solution for anyone on my situation: I missed to set the domain permision:

```
Dim permissions As New Security.PermissionSet(Security.Permissions.PermissionState.Unrestricted)
    Dim adSetup As New AppDomainSetup()
    adSetup.ApplicationBase = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
    Dim dom As AppDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(Guid.NewGuid.ToString, AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence, adSetup, permissions)
```